# How to get a data structure from inside a string (Python)

Tags: python

I have a program which outputs a list in a .txt file on a server and I want to save that list in a new variable.
I'm doing:

```
with open ("file.txt", "r") as myfile:
    data = myfile.read().replace('\n', '')
var = data
```

but obviously `print(var)` returns a string `"[list, of, stuff]"`

Yeah I can bypass the txt-save procedure but what in case I could not?

Comment: In what format is the output file?

Comment: @Daniel it's a .txt file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert string representation of list to a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/how-to-convert-string-representation-of-list-to-a-list)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use AST

```
import ast
var="[list, of, stuff]"
var=ast.literal_eval(var)
print var[0]
#output list
```

From docs

> *ast.literal_eval(node_or_string) Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python expression. The string or node
>   provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures:
>   strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and
>   None.*

If you're original data was serialized using [JSON](http://json.org/) then you could also use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module from the Python standard library.

Even if it was just `print(some_list)` you could still use the [json](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) library; i.e:

```
>>> from json import dumps, loads
>>> xs = [1, 2, 3]
>>> loads(dumps(xs)) == loads(repr(xs))
True
```

Comment: ast.literal_eval() solved my problem perfectly. Thanks!